# Prevent transclusion of MediaWiki module documentation?

Tags: mediawiki

I have a MediaWiki installation, with a number of Lua modules installed in the 'Module:' namespace. Many of these modules are borrowed from Wikipedia, and they each apparently transclude a documentation page that I don't have and don't want. For example, the following appears at the top of each module page:

```
Documentation for this module may be created at Module:Math/doc
```

The "Module:Math/doc" portion is a broken wikilink. How can I remove the code that is generating this banner and therefore remove these module doc pages from the "Wanted pages" list?

Comment: By "broken", do you just mean red?

Comment: Yes, sorry -- the links are red. See also my comment on leo's answer below. `Special:WantedPages` contains red links for `Module:Math/doc`, `Module:Infobox/doc`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the messages using [the following pages](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto/Lua_reference_manual#Module_documentation) in the MediaWiki namespace:

```
scribunto-doc-page-name
scribunto-doc-page-does-not-exist
scribunto-doc-page-show
scribunto-doc-page-header
```

If the red link is annoying you, I suggest you set `scribunto-doc-page-name` to eg `Project:Lua modules` or some other page, where you can put some general documentation (default is `Module:$1/doc`, where $1 is the name of the module).

Note that it is not possible to add categories, links or any other wiki code to module pages. The doc-page is therefore the only built in way you have to keep track of your modules -- that's why it's there,

Comment: Is there something I need to do to refresh "Wanted Pages"? I've modified MediaWiki:Scribunto-doc-page-name to point to an existing documentation page, but Wanted Pages still contains "Module:Infobox/doc‏‎", "Module:Math/doc‏‎", etc.

Comment: Are you sure your job queue is empty?

Comment: I would say it sounds like a bug then! https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/

edit: I just tried this, with the same result. And interestingly, when asking the API for `prop=links` the dok link is still there!